# Unable to properly link external Java library in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, netflix, java

I've been struggling to properly integrate [this Netflix Java Client](http://www.blueleftistconstructor.com/projects/nfjc/current/) to access Netflix's API into a very basic Eclipse Java Web Project.

Whenever I try to publish any content referring to this library, I get errors like the following, indicating an inability to resolve the type of the classes in the external library I'm trying to use.

> Aug 20, 2011 11:48:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/OSNet03] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
>   NetflixAPIClient cannot be resolved to a type
>
> 16:    String myConsumerKey = new String("cefjbgekg7566cqrp2atua2n");
>
> 17:    String myConsumerSecret = new String("redacted");
>
> 18:
>
> 19:    NetflixAPIClient apiClient = new NetflixAPIClient(myConsumerKey, myConsumerSecret);
>
> 20:    String uri = APIEndpoints.MOVIE_URI + "/2361637";
>
> 21:    String details = null;

At the top of the file I include the proper class directories like this:

```
<%@ page import="com.netflix.api.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.netflix.api.client.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.netflix.api.client.dal.*" %>
```

And I don't receive any errors from Eclipse telling me it can't resolve the classes.  Only once I publish it to the server does this error occur.

I've tried building with jre7 and jdk1.7.0.  The library I'm trying to work with includes elements that are from Java v6 and v5.

I included the library by building it with Maven and placing the directory in my WEB-INF/lib folder and then including the jar netflix-client-2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar in my Build Path.

I've looked all over the web for possible causes and tried every prescribed solution I've found but none have worked.

You may be able to tell I'm very new to using Eclipse and Java Web Programming but I'm trying to figure things out as best I can as I go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if build automatically is on :P. if not try turning it on for once.

if yes then check the project build path and look for libraries. check if the correct jars are there.

also check if your jars are not corrupted.

these are the usual problems for more wait for sm1 else to answer.

you could also try searching for the resource class that can't be resolved using Ctrl+Shift+R and see if the class turns up.

if you don't get it, then just extract the jar and see if the class is there for real.

Comment: Build automatically was on, the jars seem not to be corrupted insofar as I can see, and tried with both a downloaded binary and with a version I built myself (no build errors on that) from the source with Maven, still the same problem.  The classes are all there as well when I Ctrl+Shift+R them, and Eclipse recognizes everything, it's just my Tomahawk Server that seems not to.

Comment: Then is not an eclipse problem at all. the problem is in the classpath defined for your tomahawk server. does it accept any other libraries that you have put in web-inf/lib? you might wanna check the location of the deployment in tomahawk if its is not the same then check if the jar is present there.

Comment: Interesting, is there something I need to do to especially configure the Tomahawk server to accept this outside library?  I was under the impression that when I "built as server" in Eclipse, there were no real differences between what Eclipse said the server could run and what the server could actually run.  I suppose that was pretty naive.  The other external libraries I'm using are in metadata/plug-ins, and they are working properly.  I'll try to place the netflix library there as well and see what happens.

Comment: I'm telling eclipse to publish the library to the server, but I don't know how to check to see if it's actually on there.  I don't think this resolves the issue, but maybe I'm missing something about how to publish the dependency properly?

Comment: just go and add the jar to the same place as the other jars. you will alteast not be blocked by this issue.

Comment: I did that, didn't help things

Comment: can you please check the package of this NetFlixAPIClient class?

Comment: The jar package, which contains NetflixAPIClient, is listed under the Apache Tomcat v7.0 Libraries section, and within that is NetflixAPIClient.class.  This is what you wanted me to check, right?

Comment: By taking the class folder of the source and placing it in a new class folder in Web-INF I was able to get past the first error and now it seems to just be an issue of Maven not correctly resolving any of the dependencies of those classes, so I'm downloading them all myself now and hopefully this will allow everything to build and fix things, will let you know.

Comment: Ok, got everything working!  The issue was that Maven was not correctly resolving the dependencies of the library I was importing, and the error of not being able to find the dependencies for this library was screwing around with the netflix library being resolved properly, and giving cryptic error messages.  Putting the classes in the right folder helped to make the error messages a little clearer and by going through and downloading all the necessary dependencies for the netflix api, I was able to make everything work.